# MVC doesn't accept parameter as enum

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, enums

I'm trying to pass a parameter from js via AJAX call to my MVC controller but it's interpreting it as null. Is their a way to fix this?

**AJAX call**

```
service.GetYearsByType = function (docType) {
    var response = $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: '/Budget/GetYearsByType/' + docType
    });
    return response;
}
```

**MVC**

```
public ActionResult GetYearsByType(DocType? docType)
{
    .....
}
```

I tried changing the `http` call to `POST` but it still didn't work. I changed `docType?` to `int?` and mvc was able to identify it so the problem must be the `enum` variable `DocType`

Comment: you may accept my answer if it was helpful for you. Thank you.

Comment: Need to check Routing part. Or you can accept input as string and then do Enum.Parse inside GetYearsByType

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont think so, parameter enum type cause of issue. You may try this one:

```
service.GetYearsByType = function (docType) {
    $.ajax({

    method: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    url: '/Budget/GetYearsByType/',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: { 'docType': docType},
    success: function (data) {
        alert('scuess');
    },
    error: function (xhr) {
        alert(xhr.responseText);
    },
    });
}
```

Comment: OP's method is GET while your answer has POST method.

Comment: @Amit Already answer was 'GET' but it didn't work so I changed it to 'POST' and it worked.

Comment: @klent- GET did not work because you were passing string and expecting object.